# Can JavaScript render HTML code in a PowerPoint?

Tags: javascript, html, powerpoint, html-rendering, outsystems

How can I render an HTML string in a PowerPoint document?

```
const htmlString = "<ul>
                     <li>Good</li>
                     <li>Bad</li>
                     <li>Medium</li>
                   </ul>";
```

can be converted to this in a powerpoint -

- Good
- Bad
- Medium

I'm actually using this to convert the HTML code to a powerpoint using pptxGenjs. I'm using OutSystems for this. So, it saves the custom input box with editable items (list, bold, italics, ...) as HTML in the database.

Comment: Why do you want the console to render HTML? It seems orthogonal to what you're actually doing.

Comment: The user-visible behavior of `console` is implementation-defined, it isn't part of the HTML/DOM specification.

Comment: @DaveNewton Actually not in the console, but in a powerpoint. I was asking if its possible for JavaScript to do like that?

Comment: @AmalThomas: It is possible in a PowerPoint. So why did you ask about the console? You can [edit] your question, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion of different terms here.  We have

- Browser:  An application that can interpret HTML + CSS and turn it into a visual representation via a rendering engine (among other capabilities).  The elements that make up the layout (divs, spans, etc) will be stored in the DOM (Document Object Model), which is just a representation of your webpage in memory.
- JavaScript:  This is a programming language that often runs inside browsers, but can also run in other contexts.  It can create, destroy, and modify things in the DOM, and these changes will percolate to the appearance of the webpage itself via the rendering engine
- Console:  Broadly, a simple text-based interface for a runtime environment in which code can be run.  There are many, many consoles out there, but I suspect you are referring to the one in the browser's dev tools (aka, hit `F12` from your browser).  Most consoles are pretty bare bones and just output plain text with minimal formatting - they aren't intended to be used as a GUI.  That said, I suppose it would be possible for a hypothetical console application to render HTML code like a browser does, but to the best of my knowledge, none of them do this today.

Comment: Ehhh and now OP has edited his post to ask a completely different question :(

Answer (score -3):

Render the HTML in a web browser (open your .html file with a web browser) then copy and paste the rendered HTML in to Powerpoint.

Comment: what's wrong w my answer? You can copy/paste an HTML unordered list directly into Powerpoint and it will preserve the formatting.

Comment: They’re generating a PowerPoint using PptxGenjs. A manual step probably doesn’t help.

Comment: Good Lord. It's a real Rube Goldberg machine.